# How to implement Paypal checkout option in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, paypal, payment-gateway, payment

I am make an M-Commerce application with the use of `Xamarin.Forms` in that user is able to checkout with payment integration and I have to use paypal method for checkout option and I am using **.NET Standard** project and project is also refer to the `UWP`. I check default paypal with example but I am not getting help.

I have new in payment integration method.

Can anyone look into this and suggest me what should I have to do in that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Paypal Forms](https://github.com/AlejandroRuiz/PayPal.Forms) plugin for this:

In MainActivity(Android)/AppDelegate(iOS) after "Forms.Init()" call the Init method with your PayPal config value

```
global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init ();
var config = new PayPalConfiguration(PayPalEnvironment.NoNetwork,"Your PayPal ID from 
https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications/")
{
//If you want to accept credit cards
AcceptCreditCards = true,
//Your business name
MerchantName = "Test Store",
//Your privacy policy Url
MerchantPrivacyPolicyUri = "https://www.example.com/privacy",
//Your user agreement Url
MerchantUserAgreementUri = "https://www.example.com/legal",
// OPTIONAL - ShippingAddressOption (Both, None, PayPal, Provided)
ShippingAddressOption = ShippingAddressOption.Both,
// OPTIONAL - Language: Default languege for PayPal Plug-In
Language = "es",
// OPTIONAL - PhoneCountryCode: Default phone country code for PayPal Plug-In
PhoneCountryCode = "52",
};

 //iOS
 CrossPayPalManager.Init(config);

//Android
 CrossPayPalManager.Init(config, this);
 ...
```

You can find all the important API's on their Github itself.

In case of issues or anything of that sort feel free to revert